# Create button on Main Window and save stream to file

Tags: c#, button, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I have a function to have a Record button

```
    protected void StartRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start Recording");
        //string generatedName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string generatedName = @"c:\Desktop\Stream.recorded";
        //recordStreamPathAndName = @"C:" + generatedName + ".recorded";
        //this.recordStream = File.Create(recordStreamPathAndName);
        this.recordStream = File.Create(generatedName);
        this.Recorder = new KinectRecorder(KinectRecordOptions.Color | KinectRecordOptions.Skeletons, recordStream);
    }
```

Will this code allow me to create the record button?
If it does how do I create it to show on the main window and to actually start the recording?
Answer here:
Here is the .xaml code

```
  <Button Click ="StartRecord" DataContext="{Binding}" Name="StartRecording" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="709" Canvas.Top="0" />
```

Update: Button created and file created. But nothing is saved to file.

```
    void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
          // some stuff

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
          if (skeletonFrame == null)
          {
              return;
          }


           // Start recorder
            this.StartRecord(sender, e);  
         // parameter asks for (object, Routedeventargs)
         // but I have only (object, AllFramesReadyargs) declared in this function.


         // some stuff here

        }
   }
```

Comment: No buttons getting created there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the button in your XAML and hook it up to a callback.  Something like:

```
<Button Click="StartRecord">
```

In your code-behind your function declaration would look like:

```
private void StartRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // code here
}
```

Tell your program what you want to do when the button is clicked in there.

Comment: I have the button showing, but how do I know when I click it, that anything is happening???

Comment: I don't know what you want to do when the sure clicks the button.  When you click the button any code in the callback function will be called - do what you want in it to know something is happening.  If you are unsure how WPF works with controls and actions I suggest you read up on that before hitting Kinect development.

Comment: I have created the file, but I can't tell if the recorder is actually recording and sending the information to the file. When I checked the file created, the file size showed that nothing got saved. To do it would I have to call my StartRecord function in my AllFramesReady function? If I do, how do i call out the parameters since my AllFramesReady has AllFramesReadyEventArgs as a parameter while my StartRecord has RoutedEventArgs as a parameter.

Comment: i am trying to call this function.....     protected void StartRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      ................ in function .............  void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)       ...........   by using this command ............. this.StartRecord(sender, e);   ..........in order to get it to start the recorder for skeleton data ...... which is in that function. As previously mentioned the parameters dont match up. How do I correct this?

Comment: I've addressed this in the other question you started.